# Extend the height of the div # leftcontent with the div # wrap

Tags: css, html, height

See the complete code for this page [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/31/) link, and [in the end result](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/31/embedded/result/).

My div # wrap (blue) contains the entire contents of the page, I have several divs inside it and one of them is the # leftcontent would like to stay with the height at the bottom of the page (even the # wrap div.

Basically, the red line (at bottom of page) should sit on the blue line (at bottom of page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css rule:

```
div#wrap {
    /* the other css rules for this selector */
    position: relative;
}
```

And replace the css for `div#powered` with this:

```
div#powered {
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 2px;
}
```

Live test : http://jsfiddle.net/moeishaa/VB8L9/

Comment: Does not work. He must grow as the #wrap grows. I'm doing this because I need that div #footer is aligned to the center of #leftcontent and always at the bottom of the div#wrap

Answer (score 0):

Setting the containing element (in this case #wrap) to `position:relative` and then setting `position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0` will work, but will require you to set a height element of some kind to your #wrap div.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `div#powered` has a `clear:both` on it.  An alternate way to position that div would be to use positioning (make sure `div#wrap` has `position:relative`):

```
div#wrap 
{
    position:relative;
}
div#powered 
{
   position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0; 
}
.clear, div.address /* removed div#powered */
{
    clear:both;
}
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/85unG/32/)

Comment: Does not work. He must grow as the #wrap grows.
I'm doing this because I need that div #footer is aligned to the center of #leftcontent and always at the bottom of the div#wrap